# Open .env with file_get_contents

Tags: laravel

I have a control panel where the user can edit the API Key and Secret Key, just updating two input fields. It's ok but the thing is that I need to edit the .env file of the Laravel.

I have this code:

```
$path_to_file = url('.env');
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("\nH",",H",$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
```

I know how works the replace but how could the path be? because if I use url() it says error, if I do not use it error again. I wonder how can I open with file_get_contents the .env in the laravel framework.

Thanks

Comment: I would not recommend to store tease api keys in you env file if they have to be editable. Store them in the database instead.

Comment: But if I store in database how can I get them in the config file? @jobvink I mean in the app/config.php I have two variables that I need to edit they are env('api_key') and env('secret_key') these values come from .env how could I get them from datatabase? because in config file laravel does not have to make a query in there

Comment: You can surely do this but it is not really simple. You can use laravels built-in bootstrapping functionality. You can read more on this topic here: https://medium.com/@DarkGhostHunter/laravel-loading-the-settings-from-the-database-or-file-9b4a3df5db75 and https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/lifecycle

Comment: Like @jobvink I would not recommend establishing functionality that would allow users to edit the `.env` file.  A clever user might come up with some way to read or write other ENV values that you did not intend, and that could possibly expose your app or server to some kind of exploit.  If you control the code that is reading the config, then you should be able to adapt it to instead receive values from a more guarded source (e.g. the database as @jobvink suggested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `base_path` helper ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-base-path)) to get absolute path to the `.env` file, e.g.:

```
>>> base_path('.env');
=> "C:\ProjectDir\.env"
```

To edit the `.env` file more easily, I recommend you to use packages like [jackiedo/dotenv-editor](https://github.com/JackieDo/Laravel-Dotenv-Editor), which allows you to modify environment file in a few lines of code.